# Fetch all the files present in the OneDrive

Tags: onedrive-for-business, onedrive

I'm trying to fetch all the files present in the **root directory along with those present in the sub-directories**.
There is a *recursive* way to fetch and list the files, but asking if there is any efficient way such that the client can avoid recursion and the server somehow gives all the files in a `single request`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any information about how you accessing it, so I assume you're using SharePoint REST API?

If so, in principal OneDrive = SharePoint document library. You could get as per the usual SharePoint REST API. Go to your OneDrive, it should reflect the URL like: https://yourtenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/neel_company_com/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx. Replace `_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx` with `_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef&$orderby=FileRef%20asc`.

If you're on Power Automate, you can use `Send an HTTP request to SharePoint` action.